# how to use ng-click in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write a litlle programm in angular. When I go to the url : http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects (a get request), I see in the browser a table of json. What I want to do, is to have a "list" of these objects. I mean something than be presentable to users and not only json.

these are my files :

index.html, index.js and service.js

**service.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.service('apiService', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.get = function() {
    return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects");
  };
  this.delete = function(id) {
    return $http.delete("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects/{id}", id);
  }
  this.post = function(data){
    return $http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects", data);
  }
}]);
```

**index.js**

```
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', 'apiService', function($scope, apiService) {
  var vm = this;
  var getData = apiService.get().success(function(data) {
    vm.data = data;
  }); 
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javavscript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javavscript" src="index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javavscript" src="service.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in ctrl.data">{{data.name}}</div>
  </div>

  </body></html>
```

Can you please tell me just how can I include ng-click (or any method for showing result) in my code to have a list of documents if I go to my URL instead of seeing a list of json

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a $state. Im not so sure if this is what your trying to acomplish, but first you can start the user at https://localhost:8080/home .. Then you can make a button with ng-click:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="redirectTo("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects")"/>
```

And in controller:

```
app.ctrl('HomeCtrl', ["$scope", "$state", function($scope,$state){
  $scope.redirectTo = function(url){
    window.location.href = url;//This because i dont know the state your trying to go to..
  }
}])
```

And then right after this will redirect. Then now if you want to show the url you could just do this in that page:

```
<input type="submit"
 ng-click="getJSON"/>

app.controller('JSONCtrl', ["$scope","apiService" function($scope,apiService){
  $scope.getJSON = function(){
    apiService.get().then(function(sucess){
     //Sucess Method..
    }).catch(function(err){
     //Error..
    })
  }
}])
```